# Англоязычная страна или англоговорящая?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно говорить: англоязычная страна или англоговорящая? и как сказать про Германию?

Comment: немецкоязычная? или немецкоговорящая страна?

Comment: Англоязычная _страна_, а "англоговорящий" - владеющий разговорным английским _человек_, для которого этот язык - не родной.

Comment: Официальным литературным языком и языком делопроизводства в Германии является немецкий язык (на нём говорит более 95 % населения). Наряду с этим население использует нижне-, средне- и верхненемецкие диалекты (10 основных и более 50 локальных, на которых говорят также жители приграничных районов соседних государств.

Comment: может, это взаимозаменяемые варианты: англоязычная страны - англоговорящая страны, немецкоязычные страны - немецкоговорящие страны?
В Интернете встречаются оба варианта

Comment: Не взаимозаменяемые. Я допускаю обозначение "англоговорящая страна" для Кении, где английский - второй государственнный язык, который повсеместно узучается. "Англоязычной" страну было бы назвать неточно, поскольку основной язык - суахили, однако определение "англоговорящая" здесь уместно, посколько оно выражает **способность** (do you speak English?) населения _говорить_ на этом языке.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее близкие по своему масштабу — области, регионы, губернии — могут быть отнесены к *моноязычным*. И то весьма условно. Например, *франкоговорящую* провинцию Квебек или *англоговорящую* Онтарио в Канаде к таковым не причисляют. Обычно эти определения дают понятиям не таким широким — франкоязычные *публика*, англоязычное *сообщество*, немецкоязычная *пара*.

Называть же моноязычными страны будет корректно, если они изолированы или компактны.

Допускается определение «немецкоговорящие», и оно применимо к ФРГ, Австрии, Лихтенштейну, а также Люксембургу, Бельгии и Швейцарии с 3/4 немецкоязычного населения.